# How can i add posts into team site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, team-sites

When i'm creating blog subsite i have app named 'Posts'. Is there any way to use this app in team site?

That's what i mean:

[image: What i'm talking about]

Answer (score 2):

The Posts list is exclusive to the blog sites, a similar app would be an Announcements list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @waqassarwarmcse, why do you think this is not an answer? Eric says it's not available in a team site and provides an alternative

Comment: Why did you mark this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148699/where-can-i-find-posts-web-part as duplicate? It is different question.

Do you think that your current answer is correct for second question?

Let's punish you for this answer then (looks like flood by your logic)

Comment: You are asking the same basic question, how do i get the blog posts onto my team site.

Answer (score 1):

Eric is correct, you cannot add Posts unless the site is created initially as a Blog.

I create almost all sites initially as a Blog since you can add all of the Team site features to it after the fact, but you can not add Blog functionality to a team site without building it from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Posts is a customized list which is being used in the blog site. if you see it has columns

```
Title  Single line of text   
Body  Multiple lines of text  
# Comments  Lookup  
Category  Lookup  
Published  Date and Time   
Rating (0-5)  Rating (0-5) and so on.
```

So you can create custom list and create these column. but the big question is how you present that data on the page( as it present on the Blog Home page).

I think it is List view Web Part which gets the data from posts list and display it.