# Where can i find 'posts' web part?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-online, blog, sharepont

I'm talking about this web part.
This web part displaying a few posts (description + title).
[image: posts]

Comment: It is not duplicate. Team site don't have psots at all.

Blog is not the same as team site.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Posts web part available under Blog site template.
For adding this webpart see the following steps here: http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-adding-blog-to-existing.html

Comment: That is not what i mean. Post updated.